# como mantengo una opcion selected luego de enviar un formulario con plugin select2

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, select2

tengo el siguiente código, estoy tratando de construir un filtro al estilo de excel con el select2. bien el filtro funciona y hace las consultas, pero me gustaria dejar o recordar las opciones seleccionadas, ya que si hago una consulta y luego otra... se pierde la seleccion anterior..

en php con codeigniter tengo :

```
    echo form_open(base_url().'modificar_'.$tabla);
    foreach ( $campos as $campo => $valor )
    {
        foreach ($pops as $fila)
                $aux[]=$fila->$campo;
        $registro=array_unique($aux);
        unset($aux);
        $cuenta=sizeof($registro) - in_array('',$registro);
        // Voy imprimiendo el primer select
        echo "<th>".$cuenta." <div class='input-group input-group-sm'><select name='".$campo."[]' id='".$campo."[]' class='form select2' multiple='multiple' data-placeholder='$nombres[$campo]'>";
        echo "<option value='N'>$nombres[$campo]</option>";
        foreach( $registro as $valor2 )
        {
            echo "<option value='".$valor2."'";
            if ( $valor2 == $valor && $valor != "" )
                echo "selected='selected'";
            echo ">".$valor2."</option>";
        }
        echo "</select><span class='input-group-btn'>
                  <button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-flat' onclick='this.form.submit();'>Go!</button>
                </span>
          </div>";
        echo "</th>";
    }
    echo form_close();
```

y en mi vista tengo el  siguiente javascript:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('.select2').select2()
       })
</script>
```

**a pesar de que tengo el selected no deja las opciones seleccionadas.-  alguien me podria ayudar?**

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solucion, en la vista modifique el script para que construya el array de elementos seleccionados: en mi caso los tomo del formulario que envío... saludos

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    //Initialize Select2 Elements
      <? echo "var preload_data = [";
       foreach($campos as $clave => $valor)
                if($this->input->post($clave))
                    foreach($this->input->post($clave) as $vall)
                            echo  "'".$vall."',";
                        echo "];";
                   ?>
   //   var preload_data = ['Kevin','Hector','CRM Austral'];
     // alert(preload_data);
    $('.select2').select2()
      $('.select2').val(preload_data).trigger('change');
       })
</script>
```